# unable to launch appium node in latest appium using appium grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

i am able to launch hub. I have created the blow node.json

```
{  
   "capabilities":[  
      {  
         "browserName":"",
         "version":"4.4.2",
         "maxInstances":2,
         "platform":"ANDROID",
         "deviceName":"5203b75de26b14cb"
      }
   ],
   "configuration":{  
      "nodeTimeout":120,
      "port":4728,
      "hubPort":4444,
      "proxy":"org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
      "url":"http://127.0.0.1.4728/wd/hub",
      "hub":"127.0.0.1:4444/grid/register",
      "hubHost":"127.0.0.1",
      "nodePolling":2000,
      "registerCycle":10000,
      "register":true,
      "cleanUpCycle":2000,
      "timeout":30000,
      "maxSession":2
   }
}
```

But when i am create node using the below command

```
node.exe C:\Users\sjt\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\build\lib\main.js –address 127.0.0.1 –port 4723 -bp 2252 –udid 5203b75de26b14cb --nodeconfig D:\helo\node1.json –session-override
```

[image]

Is the command to launch node using grid in latest appium version is correct

Comment: place your error code here

Comment: i have already pasted. check the question please.. there is ERROR writen in bold letter. You have to click on that and an image will be displayed

Comment: is the command to launch  node using grid in latest appium version is correct

Comment: SO is not working that way . you have to show your error here . you can use code section for it

Comment: Type error parts.forEach is not a function error

Comment: @heardm, add your buggy code to your question.

Comment: There is no code. just want to configure grid to hub. no code is required for that